# Share JPA entities among applications

Tags: jpa-2.0, java-ee-6, war

Suppose having several JavaEE 6 applications using the same entities in a database - what would be the best way to share the JPA Enitity classes among them?

Should they be included as classes in each WAR or should there be a JAR with the entities inside each WAR or should the entities be deployed separately?

And would the solution be dependent on the server? Currently we use JBoss 7.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to suggest that I implemented the solution for me in such a case:
In my company we have a single database for all that we are developing an ERP. Each ERP module that we implemented using the common database, what did?
Well implemented a EJB MODULE that encapsulates all data access, it contains the Entities and the Entity Manager and through it is done all data accesses.
This EJB module is added as a library in each of the ERP project.
In this way the ERP modules themselves have no access to the database, there is more clarity in the layers of the entire system and every ERP project focuses on implementing their own business rules.
We use a Container-Managed Entity maneged in a transactional environment. Jee6.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. From an architectural point of view, I think "encapsulating all data access" is not necessary, since in JavaEE 6 JPA Entities are at the same time business objects, so there is usually no need for explicitly crafting a layer between business logic and persistence. From a deployment point of view I think it's a valid approach to make a separate module as I also listed in my question - yet, I would like to here pros and cons of it.

Comment: If the entities are used in the different layers of the application then the cascade of changes in the database makes it very difficult system maintenance. If an application is valid for CRUD type saves development time, but not recommended on systems more serious due to the strong coupling between layers.
We implement an intermediate layer between business entities and logic so traumatic avoided what changes in the database. It should be clear where we manage where we handle data and information and the difference between them.